# washed out textures in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-painting

I have seen some similar questions, but I don't think my problem is that I have overlapping faces. I have also tried adjusting the lighting level but the problem persists. When cycles render preview does 1 or 2 out of the 32 render cycles then the coffee looks more or less correct but the end result is always grey and white and washed out. I might be able to fix this with an overlay of color in the nodes, but is there any way to avoid the problem in the first place?
[image: preview render with 1 or 2 cycles]
[image: rendered]

render preview

blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/17M1Bm2xdQxLtuhR7DOEmqay4WGezRiSE/view?usp=sharing

UPDATE: I turned the light intensity down and changed to darker base colors for world and sun light sources. I changed the base color of glass and coffee which improved the glass slightly, but the coffee is still ridiculously reflective. I have roughness at .5 and turning it up to 1 does not help.

[image: new render]

Final result after applying instructions in checked answer

[image: modified liquid only]

and after adding a transparent BSDF and decreasing transmission and increasing roughness of glass

[image: modified liquid and glass]

I also decreased the light intensity for world and both lights to .4 for world and about 100 watts for each light down from 600

Final version -- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z5UkbsWIKdtGmvthzcef6k3zenHixaNm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your base color is white, your Transmission is at 1, the World color is almost white and your light strength is at 10, so it give a rather clear grey color

Comment: Please don't make users go through many links to understand the question. Use the tools from this site to post images, so that they show as part of the post. [How to add images to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498)

Comment: I have updated to include the images. I changed colors and light strengths. this helped the glass look better but the coffee is still ridiculously reflective I updated the google drive blend file to match the new settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your environment lighting (world and light) was very bright. So first thing, change your lighting. Also, your coffee material has a *Transmission* of 1, which makes it reflect the environment like a glass, and a *Roughness* of 0.55, which makes the reflection scattered all over the surface, it's not what you expect from water, and it creates a rather grey material, you can't see the *Volume Absorption* effect any more.

[image]

If you don't want this scattering effect, which would make more sense, low down the *Roughness* value:

[image]

You can also mix your *BSDF* with a *Transparent* node to lown down the glass effect:

[image]